# Interpretation of determinants on commutative rings

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, linear-algebra, lie-groups, determinants

In real Euclidian space, the result of the determinant can be interpreted as the *oriented volume* of the image of the unit cube under an invertible linear map.

This interpretation conceptually depends on the facts that

1. $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ deformation retracts to $O_n(\mathbb{R})$.
2. $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ is homeomorphic to the group of linear isometries on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
3. Every linear isometry of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is either a composition of an even or odd number of reflections, by the Cartan-Dieudonne Theorem.

This interpretation already breaks down, for instance, on $\mathbb{C}$, as $GL(\mathbb{C})$ is connected.

In the generality of an arbitrary commutative ring $R$, is there a meaningful interpretation of the result of the determinant map $\det: GL_n(R) \to R^{\times}$ ?

Does the categorical characterization of $\det$ as a natural transformation between functors $GL_n(-)$ to $(-)^{\times}$ of signature $\text{CRing} \to \text{Grp}$ tell us anything new about how to interpret $\det$ topologically, geometrically or algebraically?

Comment: This is quite basic, but maybe relevant to the first question: if $\omega : R^n \rightarrow R$ is an alternating form and $T : R^n \rightarrow R^n$ is $R$-linear then $\omega(Tx_1,\ldots, Tx_n) = (\det T) \omega(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. This defines $\det T$ as 'the scalar by which $T$ acts on abstract volume forms', in a way that is independent of the choice of form.

Comment: For the second question I'm not very optimistic. There are rather a lot of functors $\mathrm{CRing} \rightarrow \mathrm{Grp}$, for example all of $K$-theory.